# Error every time I try to download a plugin for nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I've been having an issue where every time I install a plugin and then run the command 'tns run ios --device "iPad Air"' I get the error below. Most recently I simply tried to add Firebase Storage by uncommenting the proper line in the podfile. Any ideas on why I get this error?

```
Unable to apply changes on device: 1C9BDE89-3434-4EEE-91E3-09DCF9CD5DB5. Error is: Error while executing command 'xcrun simctl install 1C9BDE89-3434-4EEE-91E3-09DCF9CD5DB5 /Users/redacted/Nativescript Projects/redacted/platforms/ios/build/emulator/redacted.app'. Please ensure your tools are configured correctly. More info: An error was encountered processingthe command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1C9BDE89-3434-4EEE-91E3-09DCF9CD5DB5/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.DiF4Of/extracted/Payload/redacted.app
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1C9BDE89-3434-4EEE-91E3-09DCF9CD5DB5/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.DiF4Of/extracted/Payload/redacted.app
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=35):
        Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/redacted/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1C9BDE89-3434-4EEE-91E3-09DCF9CD5DB5/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.DiF4Of/extracted/Payload/redacted.app
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve a similar issue, I had to go to **Hardware** and select **Erase All Content and Settings**.

I believe the error is caused by a conflict with an existing version of the plugin already installed in the machine, and clearing that would resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this next time. I did a "tns run ios" and then "tns run ios --device "iPad Air"" again and then it worked for me.

Comment: and plugins may be deprecated (cause pods). These can cause runtime errors that similar yours. You can check them too